# What does arraylist IndexOf do in asp.net/c#?

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

I'm having trouble understanding following code:

```
if (IsPostBack)
    {
        int CheckBoxIndex;
        ArrayList CheckBoxArray;
        bool CheckAllWasChecked=false;
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll"); //chkAll is the id for checkbox on gridview
        string checkAllIndex = "chkAll-" + GridView1.PageIndex;
        if (chkAll.Checked)
        {                
            if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) == -1)
            {
                CheckBoxArray.Add(checkAllIndex);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) != -1)
            {
                CheckBoxArray.Remove(checkAllIndex);
                CheckAllWasChecked = true;
            }
        }
```

when does `sampleArrayList.indexof(objectname)` return `-1` ?

I don't understand that ?

Please help me !

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: The following code won't even compile telling you that the `sampleArrayList` variable is not initialized. If you want to ask a question please provide a full working code illustrating the problem.

Comment: Please check the documentation next time before asking. It's just easier that way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.indexof(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @paul I checked the documentation before i asked this question, no where is it clear what would indexof return when the objectname specified is not found in the arraylist. It only says "Returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a value in the ArrayList or in a portion of it." I was expecting it would throw some exception. I googled it as well but no where could i find a relevant search result. So I thought asking a question would clarify rather living in a ambiguity.

Comment: @user653622: Good point. I suppose it's a matter of experience with the framework. So FYI: In .NET just about any operation which returns an index of an item will yield a value of -1 if the item is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sampleArrayList doesn't have a objectname element sampleArrayList.IndexOf(cb1) will return -1

Comment: if it does have the objectname element what does it return ??

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf returns the index (position) of the object in the ArrayList if it's found, or -1 if it isn't in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf(...) return the position of the searched element in the colleciont (e.g. sampleArrayList). If your list doesn't contain element that you were searching for i return '-1'

in your example:

if(sampleArrayList.IndexOf(cb1) == -1)
{

do something;
}

if your doesn't conatin 'cb1' then 'do something'.